# How can I save http get response object in angular 6

Tags: json, angular, http-get

I'm new to angular and i'm trying to figure out how can I save in a local variable the response of `http.get(url)`

Here is my code :

```
export class AppComponent {

  private url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&api_key=MY_KEY&format=json&artist=The+Weeknd' ;
  public data;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => this.data = response);
    console.log(this.data); // -> The result is undefined...
  }

}
```

At first, I tried `this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => console.log(response));` and that was working has expected, however an assignation doesn't work.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: log this.data in subscribe, it's undefined because you log the data before the api response has arrived.

Comment: The http request is an asynchronous operations. The data will be saved, after the request has gotten a response.

Comment: This command is asynchronous ‘this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => this.data = response);‘
Like setTimeout. You trying to console data before subscribe event fire

Comment: Is there another method I can use to achieve the same thing synchronously ?

Comment: what do you mean synchronously? fetching the data from API takes time so if you want to achieve this data you should wait and do it asynchronous.

Comment: Yeah i see, the question was indeed illogical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is exactly correct. The reason the `console.log` is not showing the response value is because it is running BEFORE the response is processed. Once the HTTP request has been started, JavaScript continues executing the current function.

If you want to log the response, you need to do so inside the response handler

```typescript
export class AppComponent {

  private url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&api_key=MY_KEY&format=json&artist=The+Weeknd' ;
  public data;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
        this.data = response;
        console.log(this.data);
    });
  }    
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand that subscribe() is asynchronous, is there another method I can use to achieve this  synchronously ?

Comment: @obrassard I don't know. It's possible there is something with `async/await` that will be close, but I recommend you don't bother. Web requests by their nature are asynchronous and you should work on being comfortable with them. You mention you're new, and I understand how annoying and frustrating that learning is - but it will greatly help you in the long run.

Comment: In the response handler, how an i access each property of the json object received ? This is the result in the console : `{name: "The Weeknd", mbid: "c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9", url: ...}` but when i try to get `response.name` for instance it's undefined

Comment: @obrassard Without running the code myself, it's hard to guess at the reason. However, I think it may be an issue with the typing, so I would look into https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response. Since you have not told Angular the structure of the response (by creating a class for it), it may not know how to parse the response into an object and is leaving as a string - thus the output to the console as a string and `.name` is undefined

Comment: If i create a class, did I have to include every property and array of the response json object ? Can I add only the one that matters for my project ?

Comment: @obrassard That should be fine. The class is to help TypeScript help you make sure you're code doesn't pass objects that don't match a contract. If you have a class `Class { propertyA: string }` and give it an object `{ propertyA: "Test", propertyB: 123 }`, everything is ok since the class only needs `propertyA`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing async HTTP call. so you need to add console.log inside subscribe.

```
export class AppComponent {

  private url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&api_key=MY_KEY&format=json&artist=The+Weeknd' ;
  public data;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
       this.data = response;
       console.log(this.data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I see, and in the response handler, do you know how an I can  access each property of the json object received ? This is the result in the console : `{name: "The Weeknd", mbid: "c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9", url: ...}` but when i try to get `response.name` for instance it's undefined